# How to create global data in WPF project using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm working on building a project using WPF but I don't know how to store data which can be used in multiple places in the app. In the Homepage.xaml file, I import 3 other xaml files. Each of these files associated with one viewModel file. When the Homepage is displayed on the UI, the calendar will show today date, and the action items in the view3 will have Today's data (which I will be fetching from an API). Then when user chooses another date, the calendar date also change, as well as API call is performed and the action items will also change accordingly. So my question is where should I store the data from API calls and how to update the view3 UI?
My assumption is to fetch the data in HomepageViewModel.cs and somehow pass them to view1.cs and view3.cs but I don't know if it's right and how I can do it. I'm very new to WPF and MVVM and no one in my company can help because no one knows about the tool.[[image: Here is the UI that I will be building]]

I have been watching tutorials and read some document online but I really don't know where to start and how to achieve what I intend to do. I appreciate any help. Thanks so much

Comment: It is not required - and probably a misconception - that the three view components operate on three distinct view models. You could better have a single view model (maybe one per page) that holds all the data. It seems you are making a common mistake by assigning a private view model to your UserControls.

Comment: Maybe this helps: all controls or all view on Homepage are related in that they are displaying/configuring data of one context. That's why you decided put them on the same page in the first place. Hence they all must share the same data context. You would have a hard time if you spend each control its own data context, a view model for each button for example. You would intuitively say that this doesn't make sense.

Comment: In general, you create view model classes driven by abstract class level design decisions and not driven by controls. You design view models for pages (what data do you want to show/collect on a page) and then chose the appropriate controls that fetch the data to display from this data context. A view model class can serve as the data context of multiple pages. Design classes based on design principles and not based on UI layout.

Comment: WPF encourages a data first paradigm which is perfect for an MVVM application. Focusing on data really helps to implement a clean class design. Data first and UI will follow.